# Swift: Creating Framework dependencies

Tags: swift, ios8, frameworks, cocoapods

**iOS8:**

I'm trying to create a Database framework (DBKit) that will be used amongst our apps.  `DBKit` requires `Couchbase` (ObjC) and `Alamofire` (Swift) `frameworks`.

I'm trying to avoid using Umbrella `framework` as it's discouraged by Apple.

**Questions:**

1. When creating a `framework`, how do I tell the `framework` to use `Couchbase` and `Alamofire` within the Demo Project?
2. Is using `Cocoa Pods` to manage `frameworks` inside a `framework` a good idea?

Comment: I wonder which one did you use and what results did you get. I'm currently in the same situation and thinking about using pods in framework and am really confused. What do you suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Believe you should be linking to the respective external libraries from within your application and NOT your own framework.

For Couchbase, you can simply drag in the frameworks to the 'Supporting Files' folder within your iOS project.